# Why does Orbeon forms not validate request parameters?

Tags: xss, orbeon, xforms

While testing Orbeon forms for vulnerabilities of the Reflected Cross Site Scripting type (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Reflected_.28non-persistent.29) we noticed that it is possible to pass request parameters with script tags in them which can then be output using xf:output.

Shouldn't Orbeon validate (or at least sanitize) the request parameters when they are retrieved using xxf:get-request-parameter() or when they are output using xf:output to prevent this kind of security vulnerability?

I tested this with the latest version of Orbeon (orbeon-2016.3.201612302139-CE) and a Jetty container.
Note that you cannot use Tomcat since it does its own validation on request parameters and you cannot use Chrome because it sanitizes the output for you (stripping the script content).

A small sample form that demonstrates this:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <head>
        <title>Reflected XSS</title>
        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance id="default">
                <root xmlns="">
                </root>
            </xf:instance>

            <xf:var name="testvar" value="xxf:get-request-parameter('test')"/>
        </xf:model>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is an example to show that Orbeon is vulnerable to Reflected Cross Site Scripting attacks.</p>
        <p>Access this form and pass a request parameter with some javascript like: /?test=bla%00rje1w<script>alert(1)<%2fscript></p>
        <p><xf:output value="$testvar"/></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Output should escape all markup unless you use `mediatype="text/html"`. However, I don't think the problem is with sanitizing the request parameters: any time you take untrusted input and output it as markup in your page, you will have issues.

Comment: For reference I entered an [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3115).

Comment: I take some of that back. There is a sanitation issue, which is that character `%00` toggles the Saxon serializer's escaping behavior. More information in issue above.

Comment: There is now a fix for this.

Comment: By the way I reproduced this with Tomcat 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug related to HTML serialization. The issue is now [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3115).

Separately, we can think more about whether sanitation of request parameters is needed, including rejecting or removing character `#00`. Form data itself should be covered because it comes in from XML requests, and XML explicitly disallows this (and a few other) characters.